# Adding extra Tab Buttons to Tab Bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I started a new Tabbed Application in XCode and I was wondering what the best way to add extra buttons to the given Tab Bar is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As According to Xcode 4.3.3 When we Create Tabbed Application then it gives two ViewController. So if You want to add more you can go in AppDelegate and you can see

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

And you can see Two ViewController are added in the tabBarController and You can create new one and add init as 1 or 2 were added.
Try .......